# Выполнить выборку при условии

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 where (an.id = '{$n['id']}' or id >= (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM `history`) - 1)
```

Возможно ли в выборке выставлять условие? То есть если в таблице присутствует запись с id

Выполняем:

```
an.id = '{$n['id']}'
```

Если нету, выполняем выборку:

```
 id >= (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM `history`) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительно так:

```
(
  select 1 as sort_col, t.*
  from t
  where an.id = '{$n['id']}'
)
union all
(
  select 2 as sort_col, t.*
  from t
  where id >= (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM `history`) - 1
)
order by sort_col
limit 1
```

Comment: Непростой запрос, рассчитывал что есть такая возможность именно в условиях выборке.

Comment: Тут же вопрос тогда следующий. Через LEFT OUTER JOIN, вытаскиваю запись при ее наличии во второй таблице. Вопрос в том, что, возможно ли выше приведенный запрос подключить через LEFT OUTER JOIN? Чтобы не выносить отдельно, если возможно, каким образом возможно сгруппировать те строчки что вытащим из второй таблицы?

Comment: Можно сделать и с использованием left join, только запрос получится сложнее.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста через left join пример, просто не представляю как так с union all через left join.

Comment: Или аналогично 2 запроса получится через union all?

Comment: Если делать с left join, то без union. Смысла нет. Если уже есть union, то зачем left join?

Comment: Рассчитываю выполнить все одним запросом, чтобы не выносить id записи в переменную {$n['id']}. Одного не представляю, как сгруппировать те 3 записи, что получим через запрос left join

Comment: Я этого комментария не понимаю. О каком запросе с left join идет речь? Нужно его показать. И в чем проблема с переменной?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN подключаю таблицу.  Берет запись из второй таблицы если такова имеется.

Comment: Просто рассчитываю выполнить запрос, подключить его через LEFT OUTER JOIN. Достать из второй таблицы 3 записи, по одному из двух условий. Если есть схождение, вытащить запись через ON table.id = table2.id. Если нету, вытащить по условию id >= (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM `history`) - 1